# JSON File Not Returned on GET Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, craftyjs

I am using the Craftyjs game engine, and in a javascript file locaed in the public directory, which is correctly hooked up with html, I am requesting a JSON file as such:

```
var map = Crafty.e('TiledLevel').tiledLevel('/crafty/scripts/tiles.json');
```

In the console, a 404 error appears.

Here is the file directory. Everything under public/ can be requested directly.

```
public/
   crafty/
      scripts/
         tiles.json
```

jQuery is doing the requesting in the background.

How come the JSON file cannot be found? How can I fix it?

I have looked up the question "Node GET request for json file not working," but the file I am working in has no node in it.

The request is going to the server (vs going to local filesystem).

Comment: Check the "Network" tab in Dev Tools when the request is made. There you can check at what location is being made the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had named my file tiles..json instead of tiles.json. I checked again in the Network tag and found that it loaded with a 200 - OK. Thank's for that tip @yuriy646.